# Recycler View in a pop-up Dialog box with a Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to show a Dialog Box with a recycler view in it when I click on a button. However, once the button is clicked a null pointer exception is thrown. I've tried to move around my `layoutManager` to the `onCreate` method but the same exception is being thrown. As far as I can tell I am invoking the `layoutManager` correctly but I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.

exception error:
**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference**

Please help.

Mainactivity:

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.adder.diveinc.Research.*;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ArrayList<Research> tier;
    private ArrayList<Research> researchName;
    private ArrayList<Research> researchDescription;
    private ArrayList<Research> costToBuy;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageButton researchBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.researchBtn);
        researchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getResearchDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    public void getResearchDialog(){
        final Dialog researchDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        //set the dialog to be viewable
        researchDialog.setContentView(R.layout.research);
        //look for the recycler view
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.researchView);

        tier = new ArrayList<>();
        researchName = new ArrayList<>();
        researchDescription = new ArrayList<>();
        costToBuy = new ArrayList<>();

        setAdapter();
        setTierNumber();

        //set it to be able to close when user clicks on the outside of the dialog
        researchDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        //allows it to cancel
        researchDialog.setCancelable(true);
        //look for the back button
        LinearLayout backBtn=researchDialog.findViewById(R.id.backBtn);

        backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                researchDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        researchDialog.show();
    }

    private void setAdapter() {
        ResearchAdapter adapter = new ResearchAdapter(tier, researchName, researchDescription,
                                                    costToBuy);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /*this will set the user name in the recycler view.
    In a real case situation we should get input from the user if needed.
    here we will be hard coding in the information*/
    private void setTierNumber() {
        tier.add(new Research("1", "baba",
                              "booi", "120"));
        tier.add(new Research("2", "baba",
                "booi", "120"));
        tier.add(new Research("3", "baba",
                "booi", "120"));

    }
}
```

Research class:

```
public class Research {

    private String tier;
    private String researchName;
    private String researchDescription;
    private String costToBuy;


    public Research(final String tier, final String researchName, final String researchDescription,
                    final String cost) {
        this.tier = tier;
        this.researchName = researchName;
        this.researchDescription = researchDescription;
        this.costToBuy = cost;
    }

    public String getTier(){
        return tier;
    }

    public void setTier(){
        this.tier = tier;
    }

    public String getResearchName() {
        return researchName;
    }

    public void setResearchName(){
        this.researchName = researchName;
    }

    public String getResearchDescription() {
        return researchDescription;
    }

    public void setResearchDescription(){
        this.researchDescription = researchDescription;
    }

    public String getCostToBuy() {
        return costToBuy;
    }

    public void setCost(){
        this.costToBuy = costToBuy;
    }
}
```

ResearchAdapter

```
package com.adder.diveinc.Research;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.adder.diveinc.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ResearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ResearchAdapter.myViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Research> tier;
    private ArrayList<Research> researchName;
    private ArrayList<Research> researchDescription;
    private ArrayList<Research> costToBuy;

    public ResearchAdapter(ArrayList<Research> tier,
                           ArrayList<Research> researchName,
                           ArrayList<Research> researchDescription,
                           ArrayList<Research> cost){
        this.tier = tier;
        this.researchName = researchName;
        this.researchDescription = researchDescription;
        this.costToBuy = cost;
    }

    public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView tierHolder;
        private TextView rNameHolder;
        private TextView rDescriptHolder;
        private TextView costHolder;

        public myViewHolder(final View view) {
            super(view);
            tierHolder = view.findViewById(R.id.tierTV);
            rNameHolder = view.findViewById(R.id.researchnameTV);
            rDescriptHolder = view.findViewById(R.id.researchdescriptionTV);
            costHolder = view.findViewById(R.id.costTV);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ResearchAdapter.myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View researchView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.normal_research_list,
                parent, false);
        return new myViewHolder(researchView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ResearchAdapter.myViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String tierNumber = tier.get(position).getTier();
        //enable us to modify the tier number
        holder.tierHolder.setText(tierNumber);

        String name = researchName.get(position).getResearchName();
        holder.rNameHolder.setText(name);

        String description = researchDescription.get(position).getResearchDescription();
        holder.rDescriptHolder.setText(description);

        String cost = costToBuy.get(position).getCostToBuy();
        holder.costHolder.setText(cost);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tier.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your context which must be null in your case.
Have you tried passing MainActivity.this or this as context ?

Comment: Yes. It ends up asking me to create a private method to get the context. Private Context getApplicationContext(Mainactivity mainactivity/this){}

Comment: Try to provide a context by using the following approach.
Context context;    // declare it as global
context=this;         // in on create

try to utilize this context for LinearLayoutManager.

Answer (score 0):

Try showing your dialog with a `LayoutInflater`:

```
public void getResearchDialog(){
        final Dialog researchDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.research, null);
        
        //set the inflated view to the content view
        researchDialog.setContentView(v);
        //look for the recycler view using the inflated view
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.researchView);

        tier = new ArrayList<>();
        researchName = new ArrayList<>();
        researchDescription = new ArrayList<>();
        costToBuy = new ArrayList<>();

        setAdapter();
        setTierNumber();

        //set it to be able to close when user clicks on the outside of the dialog
        researchDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        //allows it to cancel
        researchDialog.setCancelable(true);
        //look for the back button
        LinearLayout backBtn=researchDialog.findViewById(R.id.backBtn);

        backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    researchDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        researchDialog.show();
    }
```

Notice: Every view inside the inflated layout must be initialized using `v` defined above, because it belongs to the dialog's layout, not the `MainActivity`'s layout.
So, if you have a button in this dialog's layout, you should initialize it like this:

```
Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
```